# How to find a maximum value of an index in a list of lists

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a list of lists of objects, with each single innerlist having 3 Object elements, theoretically a String and two doubles,say *a* and *b*, in that order.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> timings = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()
        for (int runnerno = 0; runnerno < runners; runnerno++) {
            ArrayList<Object> thisrunner = new ArrayList<Object>();
            thisrunner.add(sc.next()); //string
            thisrunner.add(sc.nextDouble()); //double a 
            thisrunner.add(sc.nextDouble()); //double b
            timings.add(thisrunner);
            sc.nextLine();
        }
```

How do I find out the maximum *a* value in my list of lists? ie. I want to find an indexed maximum.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Best way to receive answers is to show what you have done about it so far and explain the problems you have encountered.

Comment: A list is not a good way to store the string and two doubles. Define a class to hold the values.

Comment: Instead of storing a `String` and `double` in a `List<Object>`, you should create a custom `Runner` class to store the data and then have a simple `List<Runner>`

Comment: the best way would be to use a heap data structure, google how.

Answer (score 0):

1) Lets make a better encapsulation of your data object, call it FooBar

```
public class FooBar {
    private String text;
    private Double x;
    private Double y;

    public FooBar() {

    }

    public FooBar(String text,Double x,Double y) {
        this.text = text;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public Double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(Double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public Double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(Double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

2) Populate a list of FooBars

```
    List<FooBar> points = new ArrayList<FooBar>();

    for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
        FooBar f = new FooBar("Text" + i,
        ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0, 100),
        ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0, 100));
        points.add(f);
    }
```

3) Use streams.max (with Comparator)

```
    Optional<FooBar> maxFooBar = points.stream().max(new Comparator<FooBar>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(FooBar o1, FooBar o2) {
            return o1.getX().compareTo(o2.getX());
        }
    });

    System.out.println("Max Point: " + maxFooBar.get().getX());
```

4) Or use Collections.max

```
    FooBar maxFooBar = Collections.max(points, new Comparator<FooBar>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(FooBar o1, FooBar o2) {
            return o1.getX().compareTo(o2.getX());
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Max Point: " + maxFooBar.getX());
```

5) Or just sort the list yourself and get the first item (if sorted Descending; get last if Ascending)

```
    points.sort(new Comparator<FooBar>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(FooBar o1, FooBar o2) {
            return -1 * o1.getX().compareTo(o2.getX());
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Max Point: " + points.get(0).getX());
```

Comment: Should be `double`, not `Double`.

Comment: #3 and #4 should use `max(Comparator.comparingDouble(FooBar::getX))`

Answer (score 0):

The maximum double value of all values that are of type Double in the list of lists, like so

```
public static double findMax(List<List> lists) {
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (List list : lists)
        for (Object o : list)
            if (o instanceof Double)
                if ((Double) o).doubleValue() > max)
                   max = ((Double) o).doubleValue();
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

what if you use Comparator interface for sorting your each individual Runner object in ascending order and the last Runner object inside timings treeSet would be always the index of maximum value

we cannot use the ArrayList since it does not have any constructor which support Comparator as an argument

```
public class Runner {
     private String s;
     public double a;
     public double b;

     public Runner() {}
     public Runner(String s, double a, double b) {
         this.s = s;
         this.a = a;
         this.b = b;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return s + " " + a + " " + b;
     }
}
```

calling class

```
 import java.util.Comparator;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.TreeSet;

 public class Calling {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           int runners = 3;
           TreeSet<Runner> timings = new TreeSet<>(new MyComparator());

           for (int runnerno = 0; runnerno < runners; runnerno++) {
                timings.add(new Runner(sc.nextLine(), Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine()), Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine())));               
           }
      System.out.println(timings);
      System.out.println("max value " + timings.last());
      }

 }

class MyComparator implements Comparator<Runner> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Runner o1, Runner o2) {
        return Double.valueOf(o1.a).compareTo(Double.valueOf(o2.a));
   }
}
```

Comment: `Comparator` is a generic class, so specify the type parameter. Don't use raw generics. That also removes the need to cast. Besides, how it that `Comparator` useful for finding the maximum `a` value?

Comment: it sorts the timings TreeSet best on the summation of a and b in ascending order so, the last element would be the max value index

Comment: The last element would not necessarily be the element with the max `a` value, though, and that is what OP wants. E.g. you would sort in this order: `(2,3), (5,1), (3,4)`, because that's the order of the sums (5, 6, 7), but the max `a` value is 5 and is in the middle element.